# Spatial indexing of GeoTIFF images (Java Library)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, spatial-database, spatial-index, library

I have a requirement to spatially index each pixel of GeoTIFF images and store them in a scalable database. I intend to perform this in the following manner.

1. Divide each GeoTIFF into smaller tile sizes (size could be
   configured) or into individual pixel and obtain spatial coordinates.
2. Calculate spatial index for each tile/pixel (Quadtree index or Hilbert
   Space-Filling index or another suitable spatial index) and store pixels later in a HashMap or directly in a key-value database such as HBase.

Currently, I see Java libraries such as [GeoTools](https://www.geotools.org/) are being used for GeoTIFF manipulation. But I am looking for a pure Java-based library. I am aware of [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/). I didn't find it's capability to support spatial indexing. I don't intend to use GeoSpatial systems such as [GeoTrellis](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis), [GeoMesa](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa) or [GeoWave](https://github.com/locationtech/geowave) as my requirement is simple. Thus, I'm looking for an existing pure Java library (or a GitHub repository) that could support my requirement.

(Side note for people who have similar requirements. GeoTrellis could be a viable solution. Please check [here](https://geotrellis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/spark.html) and [here](https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/geotrellis/spark/store/cog/COGLayer.scala) for more information. Since my requirement cannot be bind to existing spatial system implementation, I am looking for a pure Java library.)

Comment: which spatial database are you using?

Comment: hi @Vince, I'm new to this. Could you please explain what do you mean by the 'envelope'? Thanks!

Comment: @Mapperz I intend to use HBase.

Comment: I've deleted a comment from this question which described some of its content as insane.  That goes against the [Code of Conduct](https://gis.stackexchange.com/conduct): "Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”)."

Comment: As a reference you could study how PostGIS Raster does it.

Comment: what makes you think GeoTools is not a "pure java" library with respect to GeoTiffs

Comment: @IanTurton, I couldn't find tile splitting and tile indexing in GeoTools. Is it available? Yes, GeoTools is a Java Library.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352571/creating-tiles-from-geotiff/352575#352575 for a discussion on GeoTools and tiles